# angular 2 formbuilder min max validation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-formbuilder

I am using angular 2 formbuilder to create a form. I want to input only positive values to the amount field.(minValue is 0 and maxvalue is 100) 
 How can I perform min and max validation with angular2 formbuilder.

**Html code**

```
 <form class="form-horizontal"
              novalidate
              (ngSubmit)="splitCharges()"
              [formGroup]="splitChargeForm" >
    <input  type="number" id="sequenceId"  placeholder="Amount" formControlName="amount"  >
 </form>
```

**angular component**

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

 ngOnInit() {
        this.splitChargeForm = this.fb.group({
          amount: ['', Validators.required],   // want to set min=0 and max=100 validations for this field
          percentage: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
amount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100)]],
```

See also https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#component-class-1

Comment: @KetanAkbari `minLength` and `maxLength` is not what the question is about as far as I understand it.

Comment: doesn't `Validators.required` imply `Validators.min(0)`?

Comment: @Drumnbass I'd would need to check, but I'm pretty sure it's not implied. `Validators.required` should still allow negative values.